# MYSQL divide results from multiple subqueries with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two queries, the first one generating a table like

```
SELECT COUNT(channel) AS messages FROM Chats WHERE message LIKE '%word%' GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 3600
+-----+
| 123 |
| 127 |
| 332 |
| 219 |
+-----+
```

and the second one

```
SELECT COUNT(channel) AS messages FROM Chats GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 3600
+-----+
| 222 |
| 579 |
| 590 |
| 377 |
+-----+
```

Now I would like to divide all results from the first table by the corresponding value in the second one (results rounded, had to calculate it manually):

```
+------+
| 0.55 | #123/222
| 0.46 | #127/279
| 0.56 | #332/590
| 0.58 | #219/377
+------+
```

Comment: May you add a sample of your expected result?

Comment: Show the original tables, the original queries, and your expected output.

Comment: What's the order of the output? You haven't used any `ORDER BY ` in your query. You might get random behavior. @BDA

Comment: @1000111 It's not my biggest worry currently, doing the details later

Comment: So you want to accomplish this whole thing in a single query?@BDA

Comment: Define 'corresponding'. Alternatively/additionally, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can accomplish the whole thing by the following query:

```
SELECT 
(dividendTable.messages / divisorTable.messages) AS result
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    firstTable.messages,
    @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS row_number
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(channel) AS messages
        FROM Chats
        WHERE   message LIKE '%word%'
        GROUP BY    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 3600
    ) FirstTable, (SELECT @rn1 := 0) var1
) AS dividendTable
INNER JOIN
(   
    SELECT 
    secondTable.messages,
    @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS row_number
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(channel) AS messages 
        FROM Chats 
        GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 3600
    ) secondTable, (SELECT @rn2 := 0) var2
) AS divisorTable
ON dividendTable.row_number = divisorTable.row_number;
```

**Note:**

If you want the result rounded up to 2 digits after the decimal point then use the following as the first line of the query:

```
SELECT
ROUND((dividendTable.messages / divisorTable.messages),2) AS result
```

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69972/1/0)

**Caution:** You haven't used any ORDER BY in your query. You might get random behavior.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has helped me a lot!

Comment: The last sentence is the most important.

Comment: You are welcome BDA and thanks for emphasizing that point @Strawberry