# Oracle SQL - Divide one multiple-row query column by another

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I need to calculate Daily Sales Outstanding (DSO) for my CFO, trailing 12 fiscal periods. The DSO is calculated like this:

```
ar_balance / (credit_sales_sum / days_in_period)
```

Here is my query to pull the ar_balance, grouped by period:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date) AS month, 
 SUM(ABS(v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.period_balance)) as ar_balance
FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm
WHERE (v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date BETWEEN 
 add_months(TRUNC(sysdate, 'month'), -12) AND TRUNC(sysdate, 'month'))
 AND (acct='1100-00-10-00')
GROUP by v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date
ORDER by v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date
```

This gives me a result that looks something like:

```
MONTH AR_BALANCE
----- -----------
9     $102,408.33
10    $163,715.86
11    $114,683.96
12    $198,223.75
1     $155,598.19
2     $123,121.00
etc   etc
```

Now here is my query to pull credit_sales_sum divided by days_in_period, again grouped by period:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date) AS month, 
 ROUND((sum(abs(v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.period_balance))) / 
 (EXTRACT(day FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date)),2) AS sales_calc
FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm
WHERE(v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date BETWEEN add_months(TRUNC(sysdate, 'month'), -12)
 AND TRUNC(sysdate, 'month'))
 AND (acct='4080-00-10-00' OR acct='4090-00-10-00' OR acct='4095-00-10-00' OR acct='4096-00-10-00')
GROUP BY v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date
ORDER BY v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date
```

This gives me a multiple-row result similar to the first query:

```
MONTH SALES_CALC
----- ----------
9     $48,975.43
10    $44,167.89
11    $48,997.81
12    $49,493.17
1     $48,218.43
2     $52,523.84
etc   etc
```

Which now leads to my problem. I don't know how to divide the results of the first query's AR_BALANCE column by the second query's SALES_CALC column, while also including the MONTH column as-is. I have tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233810/mysql-divide-results-from-multiple-subqueries-with-multiple-rows) but I get an error of "Field '=' is of an unknown type". After hours of searching, I am out of ideas. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Make these two queries subqueries.  Join them together and refer to the columns.  Select AR_BALANCE / SALES_CALC from subqueryA inner join subquery B on a.month = b.month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if i wrong.
If you need to devide two intermidiate queries result and get MONTH column, than just uncomment your queries in the script and delete my test input data.

```
with ar_bal_tab as (
/*
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date) AS month, 
 SUM(ABS(v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.period_balance)) as ar_balance
FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm
WHERE (v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date BETWEEN 
 add_months(TRUNC(sysdate, 'month'), -12) AND TRUNC(sysdate, 'month'))
 AND (acct='1100-00-10-00')
GROUP by v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date
ORDER by v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date
*/
select 9 as month, 102408.33 as ar_balance from dual
union all
select 10 as month, 163715.86 as ar_balance from dual
union all
select 11 as month, 114683.96 as ar_balance from dual
union all
select 12 as month, 198223.75 as ar_balance from dual
union all
select 1 as month, 155598.19 as ar_balance from dual
union all
select 2 as month, 123121.00 as ar_balance from dual
),
sales_calc_tab as (
/*
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date) AS month, 
 ROUND((sum(abs(v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.period_balance))) / 
 (EXTRACT(day FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date)),2) AS sales_calc
FROM v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm
WHERE(v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date BETWEEN add_months(TRUNC(sysdate, 'month'), -12)
 AND TRUNC(sysdate, 'month'))
 AND (acct='4080-00-10-00' OR acct='4090-00-10-00' OR acct='4095-00-10-00' OR acct='4096-00-10-00')
GROUP BY v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date
ORDER BY v_glacct_ybb_all_periods_cumm.glperiods_end_date
*/
select 9 as month, 48975.43 as sales_calc from dual
union all
select 10 as month ,44167.89 as sales_calc from dual
union all
select 11 as month ,48997.81 as sales_calc from dual
union all
select 12 as month ,49493.17 as sales_calc from dual
union all
select 1 as month ,48218.43 as sales_calc from dual
union all
select 2 as month, 52523.84 as sales_calc from dual
)
select 
    abt.month,
     ar_balance / sales_calc as DSO
    from ar_bal_tab abt,
         sales_calc_tab sct
     where abt.month = sct.month
```

Hope it helps.
Dionis.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. I had never used the "WITH" clause before in my queries but I will definitely be adding it to my toolbox now. Thank you so much!